# Android: actions after I click a button

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener

As an exercise, I'm writing a sort of tictactoe Android app that shows 9 buttons "under" which there are 9 random numbers. User has to click on buttons and find pairs.
As I'm adapting a tictactoe sample I've found on the net, I have a MainActivity that calls a ImageButtonAdapter this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}



//Shows the About Game screen
public void showAboutGame(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.about_game);
}

public void showGame(View v)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);
    GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    ImageButtonAdapter iba = new ImageButtonAdapter(this);
    gv.setAdapter(iba);
}
```

The ImageButtonAdapter sets an onClickListener for each button

```
for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
        if(buttons[i]==null) buttons[i] = new ImageButton(c);
        buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener(c, buttonValueSet.get(i), i, this));
    }
```

The ButtonOnClickListener sets the value image to the clicked button, I've tried sending a reference to ImageButtonAdapter (this) in order to use a checkHit() method on the adapter:

```
public class ButtonOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
int value;
int index;
ImageButtonAdapter adapter;
int foundPairs;
int previousValue;
boolean firstClick = true;
int firstNumber;
private Context context;

//Constructor
public ButtonOnClickListener(int value, int index, ImageButtonAdapter adapter) {
    this.value = value;
    this.index = index;
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) v;
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_1);
            break;
        case 2:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_2);
            break;
        case 3:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_3);
            break;
        case 4:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_4);
            break;
        case 5:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_5);
            break;
        case 6:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_6);
            break;
        case 7:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_7);
            break;
        case 8:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_8);
            break;
        case 9:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_9);
            break;
        default:
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_0);
    }
    adapter.checkHit(value);
}
```

}

This is a simple checkHit():

```
public void checkHit(int value){
    if(firstHit == true){
        previousValue = value;
        firstHit = false;
    } else if(value == previousValue){
        Toast.makeText(c, "You hit a pair!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else  {
        Toast.makeText(c, "This is not a pair!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And all of this works.
My problem is that, after I check if user has found a pair of numbers or not, I need to "close" all the buttons that are not pairs with the start image. To do so, I've tried changing the checkHit() this way:

```
public void checkHit(int value){
    if(firstHit == true){
        previousValue = value;
        firstHit = false;
    } else if(value == previousValue){
        Toast.makeText(c, "You hit a pair!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        closeAllAvailableButtons();
    } else  {
        Toast.makeText(c, "This is not a pair!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        closeAllAvailableButtons();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. This is because the statement

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n_1);
```

at the beginning of the listener is executed only after the adapter.checkHit(value) has been executed. In a few words, the program refreshes the buttons BETWEEN the click and the assignment of the image corresponding to the value of the button.
The result is a click, with the sound of a click but with the button image non changing.
I think my problem is that it's not clear to me how to get back to the flux of the game after a button has been clicked.
I've thought I could use an intent, but ImageButtonAdapter is not an activity so it cannot be invoked with an intent, for what I understand.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance for you patience.

Answer (score 0):

As this question rather subjective then common, I will advice you to create CustomViews to avoid messing with states. So you can create a custom ImageView wich will contain some additional fields, and then when you need to close all of them but two live "opened", you will just call something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++ {
   imageView = (CustomImageView) parent.getChildAt(i);
   if //your customImageView not one of pair
      imageView.customMethodClose(); //may be even with some animations
   else {
      imageView.customMethodToHighLighYouPair();
   }
}
```

This is may way to do it. In this way you will avoid a lot of bugs considering with states.